# Header and footer component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue.js, I am not using cli for Vue.js installation, I just downloaded Vue.js file and trying to learn it.

My issue is to externalize components like header.vue and footer.vue and add them to main component.

I used `Vue.component('MyHeader', require('./components/Header.vue'));` to load component but I was getting error like `"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"`.

To resolve this error I downloaded require.js file from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs) but I am still unable to load component files.

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>this is example of header and footer</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='root'>
   <testcomponent></testcomponent>
   <MyHeader></MyHeader>
   <div>I am Content</div>
   <MyFooter></MyFooter>
</div>


<!-- we need this two files for vue js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
<!-- End of we need this two files for vue js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="indexController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**indexController.js**

```
//rout file for vue js

Vue.component("testcomponent",{
    template:'<p>I am Test Component</p>'
});

Vue.component('MyHeader', require('./components/Header.vue'));
Vue.component('MyFooter', require('./components/Footer.vue'));

//import MyHeader from './components/Header.vue'
//import MyFooter from './components/Footer.vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    components: {
        MyHeader,
        MyFooter
    },
    data: {
        
    },
    methods:{

    }

});
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>I am Header</h1>
</template>
```

**Footer.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>I am Footer</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you use any build tool to convert the `.vue` files back to javascript?

Comment: No i am not using any tool, i show that many peaople using .vue file to store components

Comment: According to the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), you need a build tool if you want to use the `.vue` Single File Components

Comment: I highly recommend to save yourself the massive pain involved in setting up your own build stack by using the excellent [vue webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).

Comment: Instead of `Header.vue` create `Header.js`: module.exports = { template: \`<template>
    <h1>I am Header</h1>
</template>\` }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Single file component (.vue)

You need **vue-loader** to convert .vue files to normal js format.
If you will read the documentation at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html, you basically need to use webpack or browserify to use .vue files extensions.

Comment: I installed webpack using npm install --global webpack,  then moved to my project dir using cd xampp\htdocs\vuejsdemo, then typed npm init   then webpack indexController.js bundle.js but still getting error like "ERROR in ./components/Header.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)"

Comment: @JunedAnsari i prefer you need to start with vue-cli base code you can find it here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the comments, you need a build tool to use .vue files. But you can get all the goodness of components, except scoped css, by using plain .js files.

Put your templates in .js template strings, then call your components the old way, with `<script src="urlOfFile.js">`, or call them with requirejs, but they need to be plain .js files, not .vue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting with Vue and all the JS magic I would look into the vue cli install approach [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#NPM). It should install webpack and all the things needed for single page components then you can work backward to deconstruct the pieces of that setup.

You can also look at the examples in the vue GitHub repos. [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart)

That example is using vuex along with single file components but it is solid.

Answer (score 1):

### *CommonJS* using `require` (not to be confused with `require.js` which is using *AMD*):

Instead of `Header.vue` create `Header.js` which you then can require just like you do:

```
module.exports = { 
  template: `<template>
      <h1>I am Header</h1>
    </template>` 
}
```

### ES6 export / import

If you want to use ES6 `import` instead of `require`, this would be the content of `Header.js`:

```
export default { 
  template: `<template>
      <h1>I am Header</h1>
    </template>` 
}
```

To work with `.vue` component files and structuring, you need `vue-webpack-loader` and a build stack involving something like **webpack** or **browserify**.

See

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#For-Users-New-to-Module-Build-Systems-in-JavaScript